# Chrome Extension Paste into input element

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, clipboard

Lets imagine I have a simple page. With the following content.

```
<form>
     <input type="text" id="startText">
</form>
```

I have a chrome extension with an script that triggers on this page loading.  I also have configured all the relevant permission in chrome (i.e. clipboardRead).  The script that triggers on page load is called action.js. It currently has a single line of code:

```
document.getElementById("startText").value = "text";
```

I know that I can use the "execCommand('paste')" function to paste within a chrome extension.  But I can't figure out how to modify the above code, so that it pastes the contents of the user's clipboard into the input element.

I would try something like:

```
document.getElementById("startText").value.execCommand('paste')
```

But that, unsurprisingly, does not work.

Answer (score 3):

The clipboard can only be accessed via background pages, due to security reasons. The problem is that background pages cannot interact with the DOM, only content scripts can. Check out [this gist](https://gist.github.com/srsudar/e9a41228f06f32f272a2), which solves this problem with [messages passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) between the background page and the content script.

Comment: Thank you--I really appreciate the response.  But that examples seems pretty involved.  All i want is to paste the contents of the clipboard one time, into the content of a single input element.

Definitely following that this is tricky because of the limitations chrome imposes, but I'm really struggling to make sense of this example.

Comment: @J-B-L What it is essentially doing is creating a `textarea` in the background page (not your actual page), and then it selects the `textarea`, pastes the value from the clipboard, and then returns the value of the pasted value. It then sends the value to the content script, via message, which has access to your page's DOM, and inserts the value into your `textarea` element. Message passing is really important for getting content from the background page to content scripts, and consequently your page's DOM. It gets around many security limitations.

Comment: In 2014, they fixed it so content scripts can use copy/paste, so background pages are not required. - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=395376

Answer (score -1):

As of 2014 and [this bugfix](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=395376), you can now use copy/paste directly in content_scripts, assuming you have declared the proper permissions in the manifest.

It's important to remember that `execCommand('paste')` does not return the contents of the clipboard, but actually triggers a paste action into the focused element and selection region of the document. Therefore, the code to paste into your input element would be:

```
document.getElementById("startText").select();
var didSucceed = document.execCommand('paste');
```

If you wish to capture formatted text, you will need to use a `DIV contentEditable=true` instead of a `TEXTAREA`.

If you would like to see a working example that uses the older method of using a background page, you can see my [BBCodePaste extension](https://github.com/jeske/BBCodePaste).